# Exporting variables - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok so I have a file with:

```js
module.exports = {
    some variables that i am exporting here,
    execute(message) {

    }
}
```

I would like to export the message parameter to a different file.

I have tried to use `var msg` outside the module.exports and then using `msg = message` inside the execute function but on exporting this (from outside the execute function just before module.exports closes) I get its value to always be undefined (when I console.log it from another file) despite this value being correct inside the execute block. Please help

Comment: could you provide more deatils? code snippets?

Comment: Well its not much the execute function has some code and all i want to do is export the `message` parameter from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let messageValue ;
module.exports = {
execute(message) {
    messageValue = message;
 },
getMessage() {
return messageValue;
},
};

//import in your file where you want to access you can be able to view it 
in console
const { 
execute,
getMessage,
} = require("./Exports/Config");
execute("hello"); 
console.log("Message value from exported", getMessage());
```